# Benes permutation network proof

Tags: algorithm, networking

I've got a question like this: what is the minimal depth (level) o network with n inputs that implements shift like eg. 
input 1,2,3,4....,n  -> output n,1,2,3....,n-1

Partially answering my own question it's log n , but why it's like that? I understand that this kind of input/output is a sepecial case of permutation.

Question can be asked different: Why is log n the minimal size of Benes network?

Benes network is described here:
http://csc.lsu.edu/sensor_web/final%20papers/KRBenes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have simple switches arranged in a rectangle there is a simple argument that the width is at least log N.

Consider the N possible outputs for any given input. Each switch accepts one bit of control. If you are to select between N possible destinations for a particular input, you must receive at least log N bits of control, which means each output must go through at least log N basic switches, which gives you a width of log N.

Here's another way of looking at it. Suppose that you trim off all the lines and switches that cannot be reached from one particular input. This will give you something you can reduce to a tree. Its root corresponds to the single input left, and its leaves correspond to the N possible outputs reachable by that input. It is a binary tree, because each switch has only two outputs. If you have a binary tree of depth d, it can have at most 2^d leaves, so your binary tree with N leaves must have height at least log N - so the original network from which it was derived includes paths of length at least log N, so if it looks remotely like a network with rectangular layout like Benes, it must have width at least log N.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a second version of much the same explanation - perhaps this will be clearer.

Comment: I added new question, can You help with it ?